# Subclass a table and a big trouble in Delphi

Tags: delphi, database-design, master-detail

[alt text http://img29.imageshack.us/img29/825/simplemodel.jpg](http://img29.imageshack.us/img29/825/simplemodel.jpg)

How you can see above, it's a kind of subclass a table in a RDBMS (in this case, my favorite: MySQL) so I handle it with Visual Subclassing a base form for tb_order_base with validating field data, etc.

This way, I'm free of repeating code and some other bothering problems, well, it seems a true OO aproach. But ...

Now I got a Big problem with subclassed form i.e. tb_order_service with a master/detail approach, when I post the tb_order_base dataset, instead of Delphi first post it and get the PK ID from RDBMS and then post the TB_ORDER_PRODUCT with id filled, it does the opposed, posting the detail tb_order_product dataset first then master tb_order_base, so I get a big foreing key constraint error.

Does anyone has any idea to how to by-pass this amazing problem?

I have asked it before, but with few details in [The Master/Detail Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827319/the-master-detail-behavior)

Answer (score 2):

One thing I have done in such a condition was to break away from doing DBMS direct calls, and to instead use a memory dataset (or client dataset) for the form.  When the user presses the save button, I would validate my edits and return any errors.  If no errors then I would begin a database transaction, commit the master record (and then read the master record key back if its an insert), then run thru each table commiting the child records, followed by a commit of the transaction (or rollback if there were any problems saving child data).

I also stay away from using data-aware components.  They work great for simple utility type programs, but when you start creating a complex system using them you will find little gotchas along the way that are easily solved by using a standard edit and a function to push/pull data to/from the database.  The only exception I generally make would be for grids, but I only use the grid for selection...the actual editing is done using non data-aware components.

Comment: @skamradt: I think every approach has it's own headaches, I'm very happy to work this way although this bothering. Another question is that it would be hard to change a whole system now. thanks man.